# When iterating through a select set of shapes, how can I group the current selection and a newly created shape?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm a complete VBA newb, and the below is what I have:

```
Sub Align_Capability_Level()

Set myDocument = ActiveWindow.View.Slide

For Each sh In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange

    sh.Name = "bigBox"

    Set lilSquare = myDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, _
        Left:=sh.Left + (sh.Width - Size), Top:=sh.Top + (sh.Height - Size), Width:=Size, Height:=Size)

    lilSquare.Name = "smallBox"

    myDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("smallBox", "bigBox")).Group

Next

End Sub
```

When I select three boxes, it will group the first item in the selection, and the newly created box, but it will stop there and display this error:

The ShapeRange object must contain at least two items:

[image]

Comment: What is the idea of the code? If you select three boxes, do you want to create one new box and group all 4 together or do you want to create 3 new boxes and create 3 groups ?

Comment: There is more code, that I cut them out to simply what's needed to produce the error. But basically I end up creating a new box for every box that has been selected. That means every box (bigBox) that I initially selected will end up with a smaller box (littlesquare) in it. I want every bigBox and littleSquare to be grouped. So yes, 3 new boxes and 3 groups.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem comes from naming. The code works for the first iteration, grouping the first shape and the first created box. In this iteration, you name the shape `Bigbox` and `Smallbox`. The code will group those two happily together.

If now you either have another shape selected or execute the code another time, you will give the next shape also the name `BigBox` and the new created box `Smallbox`. Unfortunately this is possible - however it will confuse the `Group`-command, this will try to group the first `Bigbox` and the first `Smallbox`-shapes - and as those are already part of a group, you get the error message.

Try the following code:

```
For Each sh In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    Dim lilSquare As Shape
    Set lilSquare = myDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, _
        Left:=sh.Left + (sh.Width - size), Top:=sh.Top + (sh.Height - size), Width:=size, Height:=size)
    lilSquare.Name = sh.Name & "_smallBox"
    myDocument.Shapes.Range(Array(sh.Name, lilSquare.Name)).Group
Next
```